# How to trigger a Liveness Probe failure in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, probe, kubernetes-health-check

I have the following liveness probe in my service deployment.yaml

```
      livenessProbe:
        failureThreshold: 3
        httpGet:
          path: /health
          port: 9081
          scheme: HTTP
        initialDelaySeconds: 180
        timeoutSeconds: 10
        periodSeconds: 10
        successThreshold: 1
```

I want to test that the probe is actually triggering a POD redeployment, which is the easiest thing to do to make it fail? 
Possibly in a programmatic way.

### Update:

Better to clarify the question, I don't want to change the code in the application, neither pausing the container that is running.
I was wondering if it's possible to block someway the endpoint/port at runtime maybe using a kubernetes or docker command.

Answer (score 1):

You could define your liveness probe as follows

```
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - '-c'
      - /liveness-probe.sh
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 60
```

And create an sh file in your root path named

> liveness-probe.sh

that contains

```
#!/bin/bash
#exit 0 #Does not fail and does not trigger a pod restart
exit 1 #Triggers pod restart
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to change the underlying applications code, simply change the `/health` endpoint to make it return something higher than a 400 http status code.

If not, you'll have to make your application fail somehow, probably by logging into the pod using `kubectl exec` and making changes that affect the application's health.

This is entirely dependent on your application, and kubernetes will simply do what you tell it to.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get to the host where the pod is running, doing a `docker pause` on the container will pause all the processes in the container, which should fail the liveness probes.

Note: I have not tried this myself but based on the documentation of `docker pause` [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pause/#description), it sounds like that.

Comment: The `docker pause` command is not good enough. 
I can see the failures of Liveness probe in journalctl, but a new pod will not start until the container is not unpaused.